# Firebase iOS error Use of undeclared type 'StorageReference'

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-storage

I have added following pods:

```
pod 'Firebase/Storage'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
```

and imported the sdk

```
import Firebase
```

but I am still getting the following error as mentioned in the screenshot:
[image: Error with firebase storage]

can someone help me to solve the issue?

Comment: try importing Firebase Stroage as well.

Comment: When i try to import it, it shows that with a crossed red line in options, I was not importing that before, but later I did, can you tell why do I see it crossed?

Answer (score 1):

Add `pod 'Firebase/Messaging'` to your Podfile

Answer (score 0):

Add the following import to your file:

`import FirebaseStorage`

it worked for me